# Use CMake with Clang under windows targeting MinGW-w64

Tags: cmake, mingw, llvm

I'm trying to CMake a project, with

```
-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:STRING=C:/Dev/LLVM-10.0.0/bin/clang++.exe
-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_TARGET:STRING=x86_64-w64-mingw32
```

But I get the error:

> "C:/Dev/LLVM-10.0.0/bin/clang++.exe" targets the MSVC ABI but has a
> GNU-like command-line interface.  This is not supported.  Use
> 'clang-cl' instead, e.g.  by setting 'CXX=clang-cl' in the
> environment.  Furthermore, use the MSVC command-line environment.

If I run on the shell : `clang++.exe -target x86_64-w64-mingw32 -v` I get :

```
clang version 10.0.0
Target: x86_64-w64-windows-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: C:\Dev\LLVM-10.0.0\bin
```

Which shows that clang supports the specified target.

Why does clang wrongly recognizes msvc as the target?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with LLVM/clang from http://winlibs.com/ ?
It has no references to MSVC whatsoever.